# Can't upgrade HDF5 using yum on CentOS-5 because of Missing Dependency

Tags: python, yum, hdf5, centos5, pytables

I'm having trouble upgrading hdf5 to 1.8.7 on CentOS-5. The error I get is below. I need to upgrade so I can install PyTables.

I think it's because my version of gdal doesn't support the newer version of hdf5. I need gdal for raster support with postGIS.

If upgrading isn't possible, is there any why to use PyTable with my current version of hdf5 (1.6.10)

Thanks Matt.

```
[root@twcpmol02 bma]# yum update hdf5
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.ventraip.net.au
 * epel: mirror.web24.net.au
 * extras: mirror.ventraip.net.au
 * remi: remi-mirror.dedipower.com
 * rpmforge: mirror.oscc.org.my
 * updates: mirror.ventraip.net.au
Excluding Packages from CentOS-5 - Base
Finished
Excluding Packages from CentOS-5 - Updates
Finished
Setting up Update Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
--> Processing Dependency: libhdf5.so.0()(64bit) for package: gdal
--> Processing Dependency: libhdf5.so.0()(64bit) for package: octave-forge
---> Package hdf5.x86_64 0:1.8.7-1.el5.rf set to be updated
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
gdal-1.8.0-4.el5.elgis.x86_64 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libhdf5.so.0()(64bit) is needed by package gdal-1.8.0-4.el5.elgis.x86_64 (installed)
octave-forge-20071212-6.el5.x86_64 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libhdf5.so.0()(64bit) is needed by package octave-forge-20071212-6.el5.x86_64 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: libhdf5.so.0()(64bit) is needed by package octave-forge-20071212-6.el5.x86_64 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: libhdf5.so.0()(64bit) is needed by package gdal-1.8.0-4.el5.elgis.x86_64 (installed)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

My repo list is:

```
[root@twcpmol02 bma]# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.ventraip.net.au
 * epel: mirror.web24.net.au
 * extras: mirror.ventraip.net.au
 * remi: remi-mirror.dedipower.com
 * rpmforge: mirror.oscc.org.my
 * updates: mirror.ventraip.net.au
Excluding Packages from CentOS-5 - Base
Finished
Excluding Packages from CentOS-5 - Updates
Finished
repo id                                                                       repo name                                                                                                         status
base                                                                          CentOS-5 - Base                                                                                                   3,612+29
elgis                                                                         EL GIS 5 - x86_64                                                                                                      136
elgis-plus                                                                    EL GIS 5 Plus - x86_64                                                                                                  60
epel                                                                          Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 5 - x86_64                                                                       7,317
extras                                                                        CentOS-5 - Extras                                                                                                      270
home_gbvalor                                                                  gbvalor's Home Project (CentOS_5)                                                                                       83
pgdg92                                                                        PostgreSQL 9.2 5 - x86_64                                                                                              173
remi                                                                          Les RPM de remi pour Enterprise Linux 5 - x86_64                                                                     1,144
rpmforge                                                                      RHEL 5 - RPMforge.net - dag                                                                                         11,273
updates                                                                       CentOS-5 - Updates
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this instruction`yum install */libhdf5.so.0`

Comment: if that's have no effect. download the offline rpm package and manually install that. [libhdf5.so.0](http://centos.karan.org/el5/extras/testing/x86_64/RPMS/hdf5-1.6.6-1.el5.kb.x86_64.rpm)

Comment: That didn't work as there wasn't any package */libhdf5 available. The linked file contains a version of hdf5 lower then the one I currently have installed.